# Чтение массива php

Tags: php, php7

Есть такой алгоритм:

```
foreach ($mass as $item):
    echo '$item';
endforeach;
```

Необходимо начинать читать массив с 3-го элемента

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$output = array_slice($input, 2, NULL, TRUE);
foreach($output as $item){ 
   echo $item;
}
```

> *Обратите внимание, что по умолчанию **array_slice()** сбрасывает ключи массива. Вы можете переопределить это поведение, установив
>   параметр **preserve_keys** в **TRUE**.*

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант лучше всего так как не нужно устанавливать счетчики

Answer (score 2):

Вариант в одну строку:

```
$mass = [
    'key1' => 1,
    'key2' => 2,
    'key3' => 3,
    'key4' => 4,
    'key5' => 5,
    'key6' => 6,
    'key7' => 7,
];

array_map(function($item){ echo "$item<br>"; }, array_slice($mass, 2));
/*
3
4
5
6
7
*/
```

Comment: массив динамический, поэтому проще просто использовать array_slice

Comment: @Дмитрий а у меня в ответе не `array_slice()` ? Или в том ответе, который вы отметили галкой, не `array_slice()` ? А массив я в своём ответе написал для примера, чтоб вам было понятно, что это решение подходит и для ассоц.массивов тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте счётчик, например:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($mass => $item): 
    if ($i >= 3) echo '$item'; 
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

функция next ( array &$array ) переставляет указатель на единицу вперёд. Принимает один параметр (ваш массив).

Еще вы можете сделать так:

```
$count = 0;

foreach($mass as $item){
    if($count < 3){
        $count++;
        continue;
    }
    echo $item;
}
```

Выбор за вами.